# Performance with inserting rows from inside CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, clr, database-performance

I have a SP written in C# which makes calculation on around 2 million rows. Calculations takes about 3 minutes. For each row result is generated in the form of three numbers.
Those results are inserted into temporary table which later is somehow processed.
Results are added in chunks and inserting takes sometimes over 200 minutes (yes, over 3 hours!). Sometimes it takes "only" 50 minutes.
I have modified it so results are kept in memory till the end and then whole 2 millions are dumped in one loop inside one transaction. Still - it takes around 20 minutes.
Similar loop written in SQL with transaction begin/commit takes less than 30 seconds.
Anyone has an idea where is the problem?
Processing 2 millions (so selecting them, etc) takes 3 minutes, inserting results in the best solution 20 minutes.
UPDATE: this table has one clustered index on identity column (to assure that rows are being physically appended at the end), no triggers, no other indexes, no other process is accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as we are all being vague, here is a vague answer. If inserting 2mil rows takes that long, I would check four problems in this order:

1. Validating foreign key references or uniqueness constraints. You shouldn't need any of these on your temporary table. Do the validation in your CLR before the record gets to the insert step.
2. Complicated triggers. Please tell me you don't have any triggers on the temporary table. Finish your inserts and then do more processing after everything is in.
3. Trying to recalculate indexes after each insert. Try dropping the indexes before the insert step and recreating after.
4. If these aren't it, you might be dealing with record locking. Do you have other processes that hit the temporary table that might be getting in the way? Can you stop them during your insert?

Comment: No foreign keys or any constrains, Clustered index on identity column (assuring that all records are appended at the end)
No triggers of nay type on this table, no other indexes, no other process is accessing this table. This is temporary table which is used later to update original table with 2 millions rows.